Cannot boot Live USB on HP Pavillion dv6
I tried to install Lubuntu 24.04.1 on a HP Pavillion dv6. In the BIOS (fully updated) I cannot find any reference to UEFI.
Using Ventoy results in printing "VTloading......" and freezing.
Using Startup Disk Creator results in printing "GRUB" and freezing.
Using Unetbootin, the USB disk is not available in the boot menu.
The media work on other computer.
I tried to use Ventoy text mode with no result. I tried to use "Fixed" setting for graphics adapter in BIOS. I verified the SHA256 sums on each step I could.
Is there something I can try?
Thank you.
Edit: as per comment suggestion, I tried dd and Minimal ISO with no success.
I also tried connecting a VGA monitor, nothing happened.
I searched in advanced BIOS settings for InsydeH2O accessible using A+F10. I found nothing appropriate.
I tried burning a DVD.

Starting point I'd work on is what Lubuntu release; but you didn't give that detail. The details you did provide highlight issues with your hardware more so than Lubuntu, as you were unable to get even Ventoy to start & thus the ISOs available to it aren't yet being involved.  I'd try writing media as is documented for your unstated release, rather than non-Ubuntu tools.

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@guiverc as stated in the original question, I used Startup Disk Creator without success. I modified the question to add the version.

@karel I will try using dd with Lubuntu 24.04.1; do you think using the Minimal CD would yield different results? I already checked the SHA256 sums.

The Minimal USB is very lightweight and it has a text-only interface which avoids some common graphics related problems.

Strictly following the instructions in the linked question has the same result as Startup Disk Creator: it prints "GRUB" and freezes. Any other suggestion?
